# How to upgrade my asp.net app to support more users?

Tags: asp.net

When an asp.net website has about 1,000 active users, it works good.

How should I do if the website has about 100,000 active users?

How to upgrade my asp.net app to support a larger number of users?

Changing the webApp's architecture?

Or buying more web servers?

I just wonder in the real-world, how do other people build an asp.net website supporting millions of users?  What's the app architecture of a website to support that?

Any suggestion will be welcome.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First, make sure you're with a first rate hosting provider.

Second, download a performance profiler (I always suggest [Red Gate Performance Profiler](http://www.red-gate.com/products/ants_performance_profiler/index.htm)) and profile your app. Find the bottlenecks and eliminate them. Repeat until you get your desired performance metric.

Answer (score 0):

If your application is querying a database or other web services, try to use asynchronous methods.  Using asynch methods will free up the web server to handle a lot more client requests while it is waiting for a response from the database server or web service.

Answer (score 0):

You say it "works good" at the moment.  It's impossible to know what the point at which this may change will be wihtout knowing a whole lot more about the nature of your traffic, current set up, what else runs on the server, etc ,etc.  It could be that it continues to "work good" with a million users as it is.

When you need to make changes (and slowly reducing performance will alert you), that's whne you need to worry.  And then, as Justin says, knowing the potential bottelnecks will give you pointers as to what solution you need.

Answer (score 0):

Buying more servers is one strategy. So is changing the architecture. The easiest and cost effective is throwing more servers at it. It does depend a little bit on the current application architecture, but nothing that can't be easily overcome.

What I suggest, is to load test your application. See what happens as you increase the active users. Who knows it might handle 100k active users, maybe it won't but at least you will know the tipping point.

In regards to what you should do, that really depends on your business needs. If your company has the $$ and this is a core product, then it makes sense to architect a robust application. If it's not, maybe throwing hardware at the problem is good enough.

It would also help if you could define an active user. Is it someone who is visiting your site and has a session? Is it 100k concurrent requests to the server...?

Answer (score 0):

In terms of hardware scaling: Scaling Up or Scaling out

Software scaling - Profile your app